# 'RegistrarPersonaIndependieteForm' object has no attribute 'edad'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

Tengo este formulario para registrar un usuario, pero el clean del campo edad me dice que el formulario no posee este atributo

```
class RegistrarPersonaIndependieteForm(UserCreationForm):
    ....
    edad = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'sector_economico', 'celular',
                  'first_name', 'last_name', 'tipo_identificacion', 'edad']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrarPersonaIndependieteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ....
        self.fields['edad'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'input is-large'

    def clean_edad(self):
        from dubs2.desarrollo_empresarial.validators import edad_empleado_valida
        try:
            edad_empleado_valida(self.edad)
        except Exception:
            raise ValidationError('No se encuentra en el rango de edades permitidas')
        return self.edad
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que acceder al atributo [`cleaned_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data), dicho atributo es para acceder a los datos del formulario ya validados y "limpios", si los datos no se validan, el **diccionario** [`cleaned_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data) contiene solo los campos válidos:

```
def clean_edad(self):
    from dubs2.desarrollo_empresarial.validators import edad_empleado_valida
    edad = self.cleaned_data.get('edad')

    try:
        edad_empleado_valida(edad)
    except Exception:
        raise ValidationError('No se encuentra en el rango de edades permitidas')

    return edad
```

Eso soluciona tu problema.

---

Por otra parte si tienes la duda de porque no existe el atributo `edad` (algo que me pareció raro, así que replique tu código y obtuve el mismo error), es porque así lo programaron o desarrollaron los desarrolladores de Django y esto se puede ver en la metaclase [`DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L22):

```
class DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass(MediaDefiningClass):
    """Collect Fields declared on the base classes."""
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        # Collect fields from current class.
        current_fields = []
        for key, value in list(attrs.items()):
            if isinstance(value, Field):
                current_fields.append((key, value))
                attrs.pop(key) # <----
        attrs['declared_fields'] = dict(current_fields)

    ...
```

La metaclase [`ModelFormMetaclass`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/92309e53d9921a60e667656d8dd65e59eb5cf81c/django/forms/models.py#L208) hereda de dicha metaclase y a su ves es la metaclase de la clase [`ModelForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L471):

```
class ModelForm(BaseModelForm, metaclass=ModelFormMetaclass):
    pass
```

Los motivos del porque lo hicieron así, no lo se y creo que no es necesario saberlo.

Espero haberte ayudado.